# Jenkins mailer Issue with pipeline jobs

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

When i configure my jenkins pipeline job for the first build mail is coming correctly. **After second or third build its throwing below error**.

Exception raised during template rendering: No such property: author for class: hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: author for class: hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53) at

Success Jenkins mail received[image] 
Failed Jenkins mail received after second build for same job[image]